# What is the result of `strtod("3ex", &end)` supposed to be? What about `sscanf`?

Tags: c, scanf, standard-library, strtod

In my experiments this expression

```
double d = strtod("3ex", &end);
```

initializes `d` with `3.0` and places `end` pointer at `'e'` character in the input string. This is exactly as I would expect it to behave. The `'e'` character might look as a beginning of the exponent part, but since the actual exponent value (required by 6.4.4.2) is missing, that `'e'` should be treated as a completely independent character.

However, when I do

```
double d;
char c;
sscanf("3ex", "%lf%c", &d, &c);
```

I notice that `sscanf` consumes both `'3'` and `'e'` for the `%lf` format specifier. Variable `d` receives `3.0` value. Variable `c` ends up with `'x'` in it. This look strange to me for two reasons.

Firstly, since the language specification refers to `strtod` when describing the behavior of `%f` format specifier, I intuitively expected `%lf` to treat the input the same way `strtod` does (i.e. choose the same position as the termination point). However, I know that historically `scanf` was supposed to return no more than one character back to the input stream. That limits the distance of any look-ahead `scanf` can perform by one character. And the example above requires at least two character look-ahead. So, let's say I accept the fact that `%lf` consumed both `'3'` and `'e'` from the input stream.

But then we run into the second issue. Now `sscanf` has to convert that `"3e"` to type `double`. `"3e"` is not a valid representation of a floating-point constant (again, according to 6.4.4.2 the exponent value is not optional). I would expect `sscanf` to treat this input as erroneous: terminate during `%lf` conversion, return `0` and leave `d` and  `c` unchanged. However, the above `sscanf` completes successfully (returning `2`).

This behavior is consistent between GCC and MSVC implementations of standard library.

So, my question is, where exactly in the C language standard document does it allow `sscanf` to behave as described above, referring to the above two points: consuming more than `strtod` does and successfully converting such sequences as `"3e"`?

By looking at my experiment results I can probably "reverse engineer" the `sscanf`'s behavior: consume as much as "looks right" never stepping back and then just pass the consumed sequence to `strtod`. That way that `'e'` gets consumed by `%lf` and then just ignored by `strtod`. But were exactly is all that in the language specification?

Comment: Perhaps the reason (though not a very good excuse) to the difference lies in the fact that `sscanf` is in `stdio` and `strtod` is in `stdlib`.

Comment: Not really sure I understand: why does the result of sscanf seem strange to you? What exactly did you expect? Could you please give a bit more details?

Comment: @HighPredator: OP probably means that variable `c` should attain the value `'e'` and not the value `'x'`. Or perhaps it should not attain any value at all, and function `sscanf` should return 1 instead of 2 (so it accurately emulates the behavior of `strtod`).

Comment: @barakmanos, that may indeed be the case. Let's wait for OP's answer.

Comment: @HighPredator: I actually described the two issues that I have with it in my question. I always intuitively expected `sscanf` format requirements and behavior to be in sync with `strto...` format requirements and behavior. The language standard actually states that, but apparently I saw more in it that there really was. For example, I expected `sscanf` to stop at exactly the same point where `strto...` would stop. Now I kinda "see" that the standard probably does not require that and allows `sscanf` to consume more.

Comment: But I still don't see where the standard allows successful conversion in cases when `sscanf` decided to "consume more" and the result of that consumption does not match the syntax requirements.

Comment: While the behaviour you observed seems a little odd, there's no requirement that `sscanf` and `strtod` should exhibit similar (or equivalent) behaviour. `strto.` `*scanf()` needs to scanf left to right. But `strtod()` may "look ahead" and decide where to put *endptr*.

Comment: @Blue Moon: Yes, but the language specification defines the behavior of `f` format specifier by simply referring to `strtod`. If there's a difference between `f` specifier and `strtod`, the standard should describe it somewhere. My questions is: where? Which specific wording?

Comment: An interesting case of duplicate -- not so much the *question*, but the *answer*: [Difference between scanf() and strtol() / strtod() in parsing numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425730/difference-between-scanf-and-strtol-strtod-in-parsing-numbers) Basically, `...scanf()` is defined to take the longest possible sequence that is, **or is a prefix of**, a matching input, while `strto...()` takes the longest **valid** sequence. (The difference being a result of streams supporting only one character of guaranteed put-back, i.e. `...scanf()` cannot step back as much as `strto...()` can.)

Answer (score 2):

I just find the description below on [die.net](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtod)

> The strtod(), strtof(), and strtold() functions convert the initial
>   portion of the string pointed to by nptr to double, float, and long
>   double representation, respectively.
>
> The expected form of the (initial portion of the) string is optional
>   leading white space as recognized by isspace(3), an optional plus
>   ('+') or minus sign ('-') and then either (i) a decimal number, or
>   (ii) a hexadecimal number, or (iii) an infinity, or (iv) a NAN
>   (not-a-number).
>
> A decimal number consists of a nonempty sequence of decimal digits
>   possibly containing a radix character (decimal point,
>   locale-dependent, usually '.'), optionally followed by a decimal
>   exponent. A decimal exponent consists of an 'E' or 'e', followed by an
>   optional plus or minus sign, followed by a nonempty sequence of
>   decimal digits, and indicates multiplication by a power of 10.
>
> A hexadecimal number consists of a "0x" or "0X" followed by a nonempty
>   sequence of hexadecimal digits possibly containing a radix character,
>   optionally followed by a binary exponent. A binary exponent consists
>   of a 'P' or 'p', followed by an optional plus or minus sign, followed
>   by a nonempty sequence of decimal digits, and indicates multiplication
>   by a power of 2. At least one of radix character and binary exponent
>   must be present.
>
> An infinity is either "INF" or "INFINITY", disregarding case.
>
> A NAN is "NAN" (disregarding case) optionally followed by '(', a
>   sequence of characters, followed by ')'. The character string
>   specifies in an implementation-dependent way the type of NAN.

Then I performed an experiment, I executed the code below with gcc

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char head[1024], *tail;

void core(const char *stmt){
    sprintf(head, "%s", stmt);
    double d=strtod(head, &tail);
    printf("cover %s to %.2f with length=%ld.\n", head, d, tail-head);
}

int main(){
    core("3.0x");
    core("3e");
    core("3ex");
    core("3e0x");

    return 0;
}
```

and get the result

```
cover 3.0x to 3.00 with length=3.
cover 3e to 3.00 with length=1.
cover 3ex to 3.00 with length=1.
cover 3e0x to 3.00 with length=3.
```

So, It seems that there should be some digits behind 'e'.

For `sscanf` , I performed another experiment with gcc code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char head[1024];

void core(const char *stmt){
    int i;sscanf(stmt, "%x%s", &i, head);
    printf("sscanf %s catch %d with '%s'.\n", stmt, i, head);
}

int main(){
    core("0");
    core("0x0g");
    core("0x1g");
    core("0xg");

    return 0;
}
```

then get the output below:

```
sscanf 0 catch 0 with ''.
sscanf 0x0g catch 0 with 'g'.
sscanf 0x1g catch 1 with 'g'.
sscanf 0xg catch 0 with 'g'.
```

It seems that sscanf would try to CATCH MORE CHARACTER AND WOULD NOT ROLLBACK IF IT JUDGED IT IS LEGAL CURRENTLY (MAY BE ILLEGAL WITH INCOMPLETE SITUATION).