# What is `scanf` supposed to do with incomplete exponent-part?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, c99, glibc

Take for example `rc = scanf("%f", &flt);` with the input `42ex`. An implementation of `scanf` would read `42e` thinking it would encounter a digit or sign after that and realize first when reading `x` that it didn't get that. Should it at this point push back both `x` and `e`? Or should it only push back the `x`.

The reason I ask is that GNU's libc will on a subsequent call to `gets` return `ex` indicating they've pushed back both `x` and `e`, but the standard says:

> An input item is read from the stream, unless the speciﬁcation includes an n speciﬁer. An input item is deﬁned as the longest sequence of input characters which does not exceed any speciﬁed ﬁeld width and which is, or is a preﬁx of, a matching input sequence[245] The ﬁrst character, if any, after the input item remains unread. If the length of the input item is zero, the execution of the directive fails; this condition is a matching failure unless end-of-ﬁle, an encoding error, or a read error prevented input from the stream, in which case it is an input failure.

I interpret this as since `42e` is a prefix of a matching input sequence (since for example `42e1` would be a matching input sequence), which should mean that it would consider `42e` as a input item that should be read leaving only `x` unread. That would also be more convenient to implement if the stream only supports single character push back.

Comment: I think the part following the 'e' will be incomplete, causing scanf to backtrack and only recognize `42`.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: That's possible, but the standard is fairly clear that there should be no backtracking. The `x` should simply not be accepted.

Comment: Your quote does not say anything about push back in case of an error. The input stream is broken after an error. Does it make much sense to muse about the kind of corruption?

Comment: @ceving That's said in the footnote [245], there it also says that it pushes back at most one character. Also note that the implementation is bound to peek at at least one character beyond the input item.

Comment: @Ceving, I don't think there will be any corruption of the input stream. `scanf` uses the buffers for its scans. With 'backtracking' I mean the algorithm's internal working; compare it to yacc shift/reduce.

Comment: Other hypothesis: There's a state transition missing. The "normal" format is `42.0e03` and the `e` in `42e`  isn't yet expected. Instead, the parser is still in state "integral part" looking for `[0-9.]`, and the transition _to_ state "exponent" is only from state "fractional part".

Comment: Look at the format as `42[.0][e03]` the `e03` must have been completely parsed before it is recognized.

Comment: Certain it is implemation defined.  A stream is obliged to be able to push back 1 character, the `x`of `"42ex"`.  Yet `e` needs to push `e` back too.  Some implementations do it, others do not.  `sscanf()` almost _always_ pushes both back IIR.  `stdin` is not required to be buffered aside from 1 character.  Avoid evil `scanf()`.

Comment: A slightly worse case, consider `"42e-x"`.  Need to push back 3.

Comment: Even worse: `INFINITx`

Comment: I asked the same question a while ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26334399/what-is-the-result-of-strtod3ex-end-supposed-to-be-what-about-sscanf

Comment: @Paul Ogilvie: Historically, the capability of `scanf` to "return" characters back to the stream was based on the capabilities of `ungetc`. And the latter does not guarantee that it can return more than 1 character. This is why traditional implementation of `scanf` does not backtrack.

Comment: The worst case is of course the NaNs - there you can have `NAN(` followed by alphanumrerics, but then not finishing it of with a closing parenthesis. If the `scanf` is to leave the stream to read the opening parenthesis we could theoretically have a case where we would have to push back characters filling both available primary and secondary storage.

Comment: @skyking This may explain why the GNU C Library does not handle NaN inputs correctly, e.g. `"nan()"`: [bug 30647](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=30647).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your interpretation of the standard is correct. There's even an example further down in the C standard which says that `100ergs of energy` shouldn't match `%f%20s of %20s` because `100e` fails to match `%f`.

But most C libraries seem to implement this differently, probably due to historical reasons. I just checked the C library on macOS and it behaves like glibc. The [corresponding glibc bug](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1765) was closed as WONTFIX with the following explanation from Ulrich Drepper:

> This is stupidity on the ISO C committee side which goes against existing
>   practice.  Any change can break existing code.

Comment: Chapeau for you research, but Ultich's answer without further references is a non-answer.

Comment: This is currently [bug 12701](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=12701), which has been reopened.