# convert string to size_t

Tags: c++, string, c++11, size-t

Is there a way to convert `std::string` to `size_t`?
The problem is that `size_t` is platform dependable type (while it is the result of the `sizeof`). So, I can not guarantee that converting `string` to `unsigned long` or `unsigned int` will do it correctly.

EDIT:
A simple case is:

```
std::cout<< "Enter the index:";
std::string input;
std::cin >> input;
size_t index=string_to_size_t(input);
//Work with index to do something
```

Comment: What do you mean by converting `string` to `size_t` are you trying to convert a string of digits? Please post some code and explain what you're asking

Comment: Have a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol

Comment: What's stopping someone from inputting a huge number that exceeds your numeric limits?

Comment: This another problem. For now is there a stol like method that work for size_t

Comment: What is the problem with just doing `size_t index; cin >> index;`?

Comment: @let_me_be is there a real overload for size_t with >> ? see Bathsheba answer and comments

Comment: @HumamHelfawi Since `size_t` is just a type alias to one of the integral types, yes, there is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `%zd` as the format specifier in a `scanf`-type approach.

Or use a `std::stringstream` which will have an overloaded `>>` to `size_t`.

Comment: I doubt that there is an overloaded `operator >>` for `std::size_t`. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt).

Comment: As I understood, There is no overload for size_t... but since Size_t is uint or ulong or ulongong... it would work for the right type of size_t ?

Comment: Insofar that std::size_t will probably (perhaps certainly; need to check) be defined in terms of one of the primitive integral types, there will be. A compilation error would result if not.

Comment: @Bathsheba: I only have the C99 paper here, but that doesn't say anything about `size_t` except where it is defined, that it is an unsigned integer type, the return type of `sizeof()`, and has a maximum value (`SIZE_MAX`) of no less than 65535.

Comment: Correct specifier for `size_t` is `%zu`, not `%zd`.

Comment: Also note that GCC defines size_t as `typedef __SIZE_TYPE__ size_t;`

Answer (score 22):

you can use `std::stringstream`

```
std::string string = "12345";
std::stringstream sstream(string);
size_t result;
sstream >> result;
std::cout << result << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 12):

You may want to use `sscanf` with the `%zu` specifier, which is for `std::size_t`.

```
sscanf(input.c_str(), "%zu", &index);
```

Have a look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf).

Literally, I doubt that there is an overloaded `operator >>` of `std::basic_istringstream` for `std::size_t`. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt).

Comment: I had to use the  `%Iu` specifier but I develop on a for a Windows system. See [Working with the type size_t in the functions prinft, scanf and similar functions](http://www.viva64.com/en/k/0023/)

Answer (score 9):

Let us assume for a minute that `size_t` is a typedef to an *existing* integer, i.e. the same width as either `unsigned int`, `unsigned long`, or `unsigned long long`.

AFAIR it *could* be a separate (larger still) type as far as the standard wording is concerned, but I consider that to be highly unlikely.

Working with that assumption that `size_t` is not *larger* than `unsigned long long`, either [stoull](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul) or [strtoull](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtoul) with subsequent cast to `size_t` should work.

---

From the same assumption (`size_t` defined in terms of either `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long`), there *would* be an `operator>>` overload for that type.

Comment: Tha is exactly what I am doing right now.. but I was wondering if there is a cleaner solution

Comment: I'd plump for `%zd`: that's been around since the C99 standard. Not sure about C++ but I imagine it's been around fort the same amount of time.

Comment: @Bathsheba: I have a deep, almost genetic dislike for the whole `*scanf()` family. I happen to have *implemented* them, so it's not a dislike-from-ignorance, but quite the opposite. I might *use* them in a pinch, but you will never see me *recommending* them to anyone, especially not in a C++ context. ;-)

Comment: I do agree with you although I cannot claim to have implemented the family myself. But I do feel that this particular case is an exception to the rule. Plus one, since you answer obviously contains hidden depths

Comment: @Bathsheba: [Related SO question by myself, back from when I was implementing `*scanf()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425730). The summary is that the input string `"0xz"`, if parsed by `*scanf()`, is a matching failure *leaving the argument undefined* (and the input pointer being at `'x'`...) -- unless, of course, you're looking at a non-compliant implementation like glibc-2.8 or newlib 1.14. ;-) That's only *one* thing that made me detest `*scanf()`. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
/**
   * @brief  Convert const char* to size_t
   * @note   When there is an error it returns the maximum of size_t
   * @param  *number: const char* 
   * @retval size_t
   */
  size_t to_size_t(const char *number) {
    size_t sizeT;
    std::istringstream iss(number);
    iss >> sizeT;
    if (iss.fail()) {
      return std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max();
    } else {
      return sizeT;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <sstream>

std::istringstream iss("a");
size_t size;
iss >> size;
```

By using iss.fail(), you check failure.
Instead of ("a"), use value you want to convert.

Comment: I think you mean >>, not >.