# Best way to get numbers from input?

Tags: c, input, console, fgetc

I would like to loop character by character from an input file that has text and numbers.

I thought I could just loop

```
char count;

while( c != ' ' && c != '\n' && c != '\t' ) {
  count += c;
  c = fgetc(fp);
}
```

To say get "11" from the text file and then use `atoi()` to convert to an int but I then realized I'm just adding ASCII numbers.

I'm fairly new to C and from what I understand strings are just char arrays - does this mean I have to put "1" and "1" into a char array?

But then I would have to worry about array size and converting that to a number?

Comment: The C specification says that numerical digits always have to be consecutive, no matter the encoding. That means you can do e.g. `'1' - '0'` to get the integer value `1`. From there it's easy to create integer values no matter the base used for the input. No need to store in a string for later use with `atoi`. If you don't want to construct the number on the fly, and use `atoi`, this comment gives you a hint about that too.

Comment: Quick fix is to do `count += c - '0';`

Comment: Lundin, when I made that change, it converted "11" to 2

Answer (score 4):

While it looks like the natural solution, **I usually advice against using `fscanf()` on potentially malformed input**.

There are several issues with the function, among them:

- The inability to recover gracefully from an error (short of `ftell()` / `fseek()`), because you don't know where *exactly* it stopped parsing input.
- The ease with which it leads to using uninitialized values (if the format failed to match the input, and you didn't check the return code properly).
- Some corner cases where `fscanf()` chokes on input where `atoi()` / `strtol()` don't (["0xz"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425730/difference-between-scanf-and-strtol-strtod-in-parsing-numbers)...).

All this relegates `fscanf()` to read *well-formatted* input only, i.e. things your own program had written before in a known format.

For any kind of input that might *not* be in the expected format, **I recommend reading a line at a time (`fgets()`), and parsing it in-memory**, for example with [`strtol()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define LINE_BUFFER_SIZE 256;

// ...
char line[ LINE_BUFFER_SIZE ];
fgets( line, LINE_BUFFER_SIZE, fp );
char * scanptr;
errno = 0;
long number = strtol( line, &scanptr, 0 );
if ( scanptr == line )
{
    // not a number...
}
```

- `scanptr` now points to where number parsing ended.
- `number` contains the number parsed, 0 if line did not start with a number, and `LONG_MAX` resp. `LONG_MIN` if the number found is out of `long` range (in which case `errno == ERANGE` as well).

I don't know your exact requirements, so I cannot give a good example for what to do if you don't find a number, or what to do with the text. But since you got the line (or, the first `LINE_BUFFER_SIZE` characters of a longer line...) in memory, you have the whole range of the [string functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte) at your disposal. [`strpbrk( line, "0123456789" )`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strpbrk) could be used to scan for the next digit, or `strpbrk( line, "+-0123456789" )` if you might have `+-` in your input...

Comment: Even though variations of this question come up from time to time and similar answers discussing `*scanf()` and `strto*()`,  this is one of the best ones yet for a learner.

Comment: @chux: Thanks. Together with "what is Unicode, and how do I use it in C/C++", it's one of those I've been thinking about writing a FAQ entry for and never got around to doing it (yet). Seems I answer one of them every other week. ;-)

Comment: Contact me should you embark on that and want a (pre-)review.

Comment: Thanks DevSolar. Im trying to grasp what you wrote simply because of unfamiliarity with C. I need to iterate through a file and find numbers and words that I will later use. Fgetc seemed to be the most natural since I can continue from where I last found something. I should be able to use scanptr for that? Part of me is thinking of switching to C++ so I can just work with strings but feels like I'm quitting if I do ha

Comment: @cpd1: Going for C++ is not "quitting". It's a much more powerful language that makes many things much easier -- but comes with its own pitfalls. Generally speaking, while it's a good thing to work along some "toy" application while learning a language, it's not a good idea to try *both* learning a languagne *and* solving a "real" problem at the same time. You want to first get a "feel" for a language, and the tools it provides, so you can select the right tools for any given problem. Otherwise, you'll always play blind man's bluff, and become frustrated.

Comment: I hear you and I wish I had more time to learn before I try coding up something but I really don't.  This is just a small piece of something larger I have to put together and I've spent the last few days trying to get my head around the parsing part.  Likely because I'm thinking of it as how I would handle it in Java with strings etc

Comment: I hoped the scope of that [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35178520) would have been much smaller along the lines of "How to read / parse an integer in C?" - it is fairly broad.

Answer (score 1):

Most people would use `fscanf`:

```
int number, items_scanned;
items_scanned = fscanf(fp, "%d", &number);
if (items_scanned == 0) {
     /* Scanning for a number failed */
     printf("Scan failed!\n");
}
printf("Found number: %d\n", number);
```

`fscanf` skips whitespace. It will succeed if it finds a number and fail if it finds something else.

Comment: Thanks Klas.  I have to actually iterate through the file to find other text and numbers while keeping track of them so I would need some sort of line position with the above?

Comment: You can use `ftell` to find the current position in the file. You should also consider the answer by @DevSolar which may be a better fit for your problem.