# Update array elements (access using pointers) using scanf inputs in function

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, scanf

So I have a pointer and a size of the array that gets passed down to a function that asks for user input and stores user input as array elements.

So the function looks like this:

```
int addElements(int * ptr, int sizeArr) {

int k=0;
for (k=0; k<=size; k++) {
    printf("please enter element number %d\n", k);
    scanf("%d", *(ptr+k));
}

return pArr;
```

}

It returns a pointer because I need to work further with the array.

I get

```
Segmentation fault (Core dumped)
```

error when inputting the elements to the array.

What am I doing wrong here? I can update the array elements (from random/automatic values ) to 0 just fine it's just the scanf that can't write to the array.

Comment: `pArr` or `ptr`? Also, in your loop `k` will be `size`in the last pass, which isn't a valid index for an array of size `size`.

Comment: Where is the definition of pArr?

Comment: `for (k=0; k<sizeArr; k++) {
    printf("please enter element number %d\n", k);
    scanf("%d", ptr+k);
}`

Comment: Edited it. It should've been *(ptr+k)..but as you guys explained: just ptr+k.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the way you read elements by changing

```
scanf("%d", *(ptr+k));
```

with

```
scanf("%d", (ptr+k));
```

Scanf needs a pointer next to the specifier, but `ptr` is already a pointer (and so is `ptr+k` ) so by using the asterisk you imply the contents of the pointer and not the pointer itself.

Answer (score 1):

`ptr` is a pointer to `int`.

`(ptr + k)` is still a pointer to (a different) int. `*(ptr + k)` is an `int`.

`scanf( "%d", <some_int> )` will interpret the *number* stored in that `int` *as an address*, and try to write whatever the user entered to that "address".

Which is undefined behaviour.

**You probably want to omit the `*` turning the pointer into an `int`; the statement would be well-formed then.**

Generally speaking, **recommended reading**: [How to read / parse input in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35178520/how-to-read-parse-input-in-c-the-faq).

- Check the return value of `scanf()`, as the user might have entered something that is not a number.
- Cater for not-a-number input still waiting in the input buffer by reading up to the next newline, or subsequent `scanf( "%d", ... )` will fail as well.
- Better yet, read **lines** of input (with `fgets()`), and parse them in-memory (with `strtol()`), which allows you to recover from faulty input more gracefully.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the explanation and for the link. I'm just learning C and pointers and arrays are taking a while to ge tused to.

Answer (score 1):

For any pointer (or array) `pArr` and index `k` the expression `*(pArr + k)` is equivalent to `pArr[i]`.

The problem with that is that `pArr[i]` (and therefore `*(pArr + k)`) is not a pointer, which is required by `scanf` to work.

There are two solutions: The first is to continue using pointer arithmetic and then simply drop the dereference operator (so you pass only `pArr + k` to `scanf`); Or you use "normal" array indexing and add the address-of operator (as in `&pArr[k]`).

---

A little explanation about the alternatives. The expression `pArr[k]` gives you the value at index `k` in the array, to get a pointer to that value we add the address-of operator `&` and get `&pArr[k]`.

And since `pArr[k]` is equivalent to `*(pArr + k)` then `&pArr[k]` would be equivalent to `&*(pArr + k)`, but the address-of and dereference operator cancels each other out leaving you with `pArr + k`.

---

What is happening now with the code as shown in the question is that you get the value at index `k` (i.e. `pArr[k]`) and the compiler converts it to a pointer (it should give you a warning about it though) and then `scanf` write to the memory pointed to by that value. Since `pArr[k]` is not a valid pointer, it may even be uninitialized (and therefore have an *indeterminate* value) you will have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.