# How to read a integer followed by a string in C?

Tags: c

I am trying to write a simple program which will read two input lines, an *integer* followed by a *string*. However, it doesn't seem to work for me.

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    char str[1024];

    scanf("%d", &i);
    scanf("%[^\n]", str);
    printf("%d\n", i);
    printf("%s\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```

Immediately after entering the integer and pressing "Enter", the program prints the integer. It doesn't wait for me to enter the string. Whats wrong? Whats the correct way to program this?

Comment: The input functions in the C standard library are woefully inadequate. Eventually you'll tire of them, and write your own. The problem is - I think - that the second `scanf` reads the `\n` of the first line. You can skip it with something like `scanf(" %`; note the space.

Comment: How about a single call to `scanf()` where you get both values?  `if (scanf("%d %s", &i, str) == 2) { printf("%d %s\n", i, str); }`.

Comment: [How to read / parse input in C - the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35178520/how-to-read-parse-input-in-c-the-faq), with special attention to the chapters "Do not use *scanf() for potentially malformed input", and "When *scanf() does not work as expected".

Comment: `%[^\n]` will read the rest of the same line that `%d` was on.  If you want to read the second line you need to move past the first line first.

Answer (score 6):

## What you need to know

The problem with `%[^\n]` is that it **fails when the first character to be read is the newline character**, and pushes it back into the `stdin`.

## The Problem

After you enter a number for the first `scanf`, you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. `%d` in the first `scanf` consumes the number, leaving the newline character (`'\n'`), generated by the <kbd>Enter</kbd> keypress, in the standard input stream (`stdin`). `%[^\n]` in the next `scanf` sees this `\n` and fails for the reason given in the first paragraph of this answer.

## Fixes

Solutions include:

- Changing `scanf("%d", &i);` to `scanf("%d%*c", &i);`. What `%*c` does is, it scans and discards a character.

  I wouldn't recommend this way because an evil user could trick the `scanf` by inputting something like `<number><a character>\n`, ex: `2j\n` and you'll face the same problem again.
- Adding a space (any whitespace character will do) before `%[^\n]`, i.e, changing `scanf("%[^\n]", str);` to `scanf(" %[^\n]", str);` as [@Bathsheba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2380830/bathsheba) [mentioned in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36468937/how-to-read-a-integer-followed-by-a-string-in-c#comment60548913_36468937).

  What the whitespace character does is, it scans and discards any number of whitespace characters, including none, until the first non-whitespace character.

  This means that any leading whitespace characters will be skipped when inputting for the second `scanf`.
- This is my recommendation: Clear the `stdin` after every `scanf`. Create a function:

  ```
  void flushstdin(void)
  {
      int c;
      while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
  }
  ```

  and call it after every `scanf` using `flushstdin();`.

## Other issues:

Issues unrelated to your problem include:

- You don't deal with the case if `scanf` fails. This can be due to a variety of reasons, say, malformed input, like inputting an alphabet for `%d`.

  To do this, check the return value of `scanf`. It returns the number of items successfully scanned and assigned or -1 if `EOF` was encountered.
- You don't check for buffer overflows. You need to prevent scanning in more than 1023 characters (+1 for the NUL-terminator) into `str`.

  This can be acheived by using a length specifier in `scanf`.
- The standards require `main` to be declared using either `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`, not `int main()`.
- You forgot to include `stdio.h` (for `printf` and `scanf`)

## Fixed, Complete Program

```
#include <stdio.h>

void flushstdin(void)
{
    int c;
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
}

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    char str[1024];

    int retVal;

    while((retVal = scanf("%d", &i)) != 1)
    {
        if(retVal == 0)
        {
            fputs("Invalid input; Try again", stderr);
            flushstdin();
        }
        else
        {
            fputs("EOF detected; Bailing out!", stderr);
            return -1;
        }
    }

    flushstdin();

    while((retVal = scanf("%1023[^\n]", str)) != 1)
    {
        if(retVal == 0)
        {
            fputs("Empty input; Try again", stderr);
            flushstdin();
        }
        else
        {
            fputs("EOF detected; Bailing out!", stderr);
            return -1;
        }
    }

    flushstdin();

    printf("%d\n", i);
    printf("%s\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Checking the return value of scanf should be on the list of things to do.

Comment: @rici Done. Hope it looks good now. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This simply, will work:

```
scanf("%d %[^\n]s", &i, str);
```

Comment: `%s` reads a word, OP said they want a whole line

Comment: @M.M Hopefully I understood it correctly this time. Edited the answer so that now the string can take in a line of words (with spaces in between).

Answer (score 0):

Instaed of `scanf()` use `fgets()` followed by `sscanf()`.

Check return values of *almost* all functions with a prototype in `<stdio.h>`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i;
    char test[1024]; // I try to avoid identifiers starting with "str"

    char tmp[10000]; // input buffer

    // first line
    if (fgets(tmp, sizeof tmp, stdin)) {
        if (sscanf(tmp, "%d", &i) != 1) {
            /* conversion error */;
        }
    } else {
        /* input error */;
    }
    // second line: read directly into test
    if (fgets(test, sizeof test, stdin)) {
        size_t len = strlen(test);
        if (test[len - 1] == '\n') test[--len] = 0; // remove trailing ENTER

        // use i and test
        printf("i is %d\n", i);
        printf("test is \"%s\" (len: %d)\n", test, (int)len);

    } else {
        /* input error */;
    }
    return 0;
}
```