# 'gets()' function not asking for string the second time i visit it

Tags: c, gets

I wrote a Hangman game.

The problem is that when I go into main again using a menu system after the game ends to go to main again by calling the main function, the `gets` function just does not ask me for the string to be entered again and just assigns a blank to the string.

P.S.: I am using DevC++.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<strings.h>

main()
{
    int c,w=0,i,q,j,y,o,wrong,correct=0;
    c=0;
    wrong=0;
    char a,us='_',space=' ',x,ch;
    correct=0;
    printf("               %c",201);
    for(i=0;i<=8;i++)
        printf("%c",205);
    printf("%c",187);
    printf("\n");
    printf("               %c Hangman %c\n",186,186);
    printf("               %c",200);
    for(i=0;i<=8;i++)
        printf("%c",205);
    printf("%c\n",188);
    //  printf("  O  \n /|\\ \n/ | \\ \n / \\ \n/   \\\n");
    printf("\n |----|\n |    O  \n |   /|\\ \n |  / | \\ \n |   / \\ \n_|_ /   \\\n");
    char name[100];
    printf("Enter the name of the Movie:");
    gets(name);
    //  scanf("%s",&name);
    printf("The Movie you entered was: ");
    puts(name);
    int len=0;
    len=strlen(name);
    //  printf("\n%d",len);
    char guess[len];
    printf("\nPress any key and pass it to the person who has to guess the movie:");
    getch();
    printf("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
    printf("\nWelcome!\nGuess the name of the movie:\n");
    //  printf("  O  \n /|\\ \n/ | \\ \n / \\ \n/   \\\n");
    printf(" |----|\n |    O  \n |   /|\\ \n |  / | \\ \n |   / \\ \n_|_ /   \\\n");
    for(q=0;q<len;q++)
    {
        y=name[q];
        if ( y=='a' || y=='A' || y=='e' || y=='E' || y=='i' || y=='I' || y=='o' || y=='O' || y=='u' || y=='u' )
        {
            //  printf("%c",name[q]);
            guess[q]=name[q];
            c=c+1;
        }
        else if(y==' ')
        {
            //  printf("%c",space);
            guess[q]=space;
            c=c+1;
        }
        else
        {
            //  printf("%c",us);
            guess[q]=us;
            c=c+1;
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
        printf("%c",guess[i]);
    while(1)
    {
        printf("\nGuess a letter: \n");
        scanf(" %c",&x);
        //  printf("%c\n",x);
        w=0;
        for(i=0;i<len;i++)
        {
            if(x==name[i]-32||x==name[i]+32||x==name[i])
                guess[i]=x;
            else
                w=w+1;
            if(w==len)
                wrong=wrong+1;
        }
        //  printf("\nw=%d\nlen=%d\n",w,len);

        for(i=0;i<len;i++)
            printf("%c",guess[i]);
        correct=0;
        //      printf("  0  \n /|\\ \n/ | \\ \n / \\ \n/   \\\n");
        for(i=0;i<len;i++)
        {
            if(guess[i]==name[i])
                correct=correct+1;
            //  printf("\n%d",correct);
        }   
        if(correct==len)
        {
            printf("\nCongratualtions!!!\nYou've Won!!!");
            printf("\nEnter 'R' to Restart Or 'Q' to Quit:\n");
            o=getch();
            if(o=='R'||o=='r')//Restart or quit menu
            {
                printf("\n");
                main();
            }
            else
                return 0;
        }
    //      printf("\n%d\n%d",correct,wrong);
        if(wrong==0)
            printf("\n  O  \n /|\\ \n/ | \\ \n / \\ \n/   \\\n");   
        if(wrong==1)
            printf("\n  O  \n /|\\ \n/ | \\ \n / \n/   \n");        
        if(wrong==2)
            printf("\n  O  \n /|\\ \n/ | \\ \n ");
        if(wrong==3)
            printf("\n  O  \n /| \n/ | \n");
        if(wrong==4)
            printf("\n O  \n | \n |" );
        if(wrong==5)
            printf("\n  O ");
        if(wrong==6)
        {
            printf("Oops You Ran Out Of Turns\n==========\nGAME OVER!!!\n==========\nThe Movie Was:\n");
            for(i=1;i<len;i++)
                printf("%c",name[i]);
            printf("\nEnter 'R' to Restart Or 'Q' to Quit:\n");
            o=getch();
            if(o=='R'||o=='r')//Restart or quit menu
            {
                printf("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
                main();
            }
            else
                return 0;
        }
        printf("------------------------------------------");
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: There is no `gets()` in the language C. Not anymore. And good riddance. -- Please use correct indentation. Please **always** use `{}` to indicate where loops begin and end, even for one-line loop bodies. Please ask your question more clearly. Please [*identify* a *specific* programming problem](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), don't dump full programms on us and ask us to fix them.

Comment: I am pretty sure you meant to write `<string.h>`, not `<strings.h>`. Only declare one variable per line. Pad operators with spaces (i.e. `if ( x == y )` instead of `if(x==y)`), this helps readability immensely. [Never use `*scanf()` on human input.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35178520/how-to-read-parse-input-in-c-the-faq) Don't get into the habit of `getch()` and similar non-standard functions while still experimenting; build on the standard functions (like `fgets()`).

Comment: user3121023 is right BTW... check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35178520), the section "when *scanf() does not work as expected" for an explanation.

Comment: Overall, you need to consider why you are using over 25 years old programming methods. Your source of learning C is completely outdated and needs to be replaced.

Comment: @DevSolar Sir , i guess i should've been more clear regarding my question . I do not expect to dump my code and ask people to solve it, maybe i just came out wrong . I just thought that if i show my code , it would be easier to spot the specific problem i have.Thank you for the inputs regarding the indentations will follow them for sure . I also later released that i had no comments added to help understand my problem better .Read the sources about gets() and will try to avoid it as much as possible . Thank you

Comment: @user3121023 Thaks ,,,, need to look out for the new lines , made the same mistake recently.

Comment: @Lundin Well I was just using some text books. What sources do u recommend?

Answer (score -2):

Try putting this code before the call of the main()

```
fflush(stdin);
```

Comment: `fflush`ing `stdin` is **undefined behavior**. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin