# c program - why are ints stored in intervals of 8h even though they occupy 4 bytes

Tags: c, memory, int

Could somebody explain to me why the `ints` that are taken in from the user with `scanf()` are stored in addresses that are `8h` apart even though the size of an `int` on my 64 bit machine in 4 bytes? It is to with with alignment in memory?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {

    int *a;
    int i, n;



    printf(" Input the number of elements to store in the array : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    printf(" Input %d number of elements in the array : \n",n);

    printf("size of on int is %d\n", sizeof(i));

    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        printf(" element - %d : ",i+1);
        printf("address of a is %p\n", &a+i);
        scanf("%d",a+i);
    }

   return 0;

}


 Input the number of elements to store in the array : 3
 Input 3 number of elements in the array : 
size of on int is 4
 element - 1 : address of a is 0x7ffda5cf8750
6
 element - 2 : address of a is 0x7ffda5cf8758
5
 element - 3 : address of a is 0x7ffda5cf8760
2
```

Comment: `%d` expects an `int`. `sizeof` yields a `size_t` -> undefined behaviour.

Comment: `&a` takes the address of a pointer, and the pointer needs 8 bytes. You have other problems in this code to worry about, like writing to invalid locations (`a` isn't pointing anywhere valid!)

Comment: `printf("address of a is %p\n", (void *)(a+i));` will show the pointer going up by `sizeof(int)` (4).

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {

    int *a;
    int i, n;
```

Is there any code following you omitted? If not, `a` is now an uninitialized pointer with indeterminate value.

```
    printf("address of a is %p\n", &a+i);
```

Here you take the *address of `a`* using the `&` operator. The result is a *pointer to `a`*, IOW a pointer to a pointer. The size of a pointer on a 64bit system is 8, so this should answer your question.

```
    scanf("%d",a+i);
```

and here you write to some "random" memory location. This is *undefined behavior*

---

For your reference, the fixed program for what you seem to want to do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // <- needed for malloc()/free()

// use a standard prototype, void main() is not standard:
int main(void) {

    int *a;
    int i, n;

    printf(" Input the number of elements to store in the array : ");
    if (scanf("%d",&n) != 1)
    {
        // check for errors!
        return 1;
    }

    // allocate memory:
    a = malloc(n * sizeof(int));

    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        printf(" element - %d : ",i+1);
        if (scanf("%d", a+i) != 1)
        {
            // again, check for errors!
            return 1;
        }
    }

    // [...]

    // when done, free memory:
    free(a);

    return 0;
}
```

For learning how to do the input more robustly, read documentation on `scanf()`, `fgets()`, `strtol()` ... I prepared [a little document](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html), but there are a lot of other resources available online, e.g. [this FAQ on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35178520/how-to-read-parse-input-in-c-the-faq).

Comment: Also, if you are using a Microsoft compiler, look at safer versions of scanf (e.g. s_scanf) that prevent buffer overflows.

Comment: @Neil no, `scanf_s` is completely unnecessary and just an attempt on vendor lock-in. For conversions to strings, just use `scanf()` with proper field-widths.

Comment: Really?  so there is no buffer overflow possible in scanf("%s", charArray) ?

Comment: @Neil 1) The MS libs bounds checking functions are not all compatgible with the standard functions - despite the same names, which is a complete no-go already. 2) You can limit the number of characters read with the normal function. Nothing gained.

Comment: @Neil the solution is not `scanf_s()` but `scanf("%19s", ...)` if array size is 20. Or better yet, use `fgets()` and similar.

Comment: I agree about `fscanf_s` being unnecessary. However, there are standard functions with those names (see my comment above). Problem is they are optional and basically unnecessary, thus not often implemented.

Comment: @Olaf which standard function are you talking about? I'm pretty sure `scanf_s()` doesn't exist in the standard ...

Comment: Considering the number of posts here which mis-use `scanf_s()` it IMO is no safer than `scanf()`.

Comment: Which is better, using something where the width of the input is completely separate to the destination (e.g. in a format string), or something where the destination is inseparable (e.g. in a sizeof) ?

Comment: @FelixPalmen: Et voila: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#K.3.5.3.4

Comment: @FelixPalmen: Annex K of ISO/IEC 9899:2011 contains (a slight superset of) the functions defined in TR 24731-1.  They are an optional feature in C11.  There is a proposal to remove them from the next revision of the C standard.  See [Do you use the TR 24731 'safe' functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372980/do-you-use-the-tr-24731-safe-functions) for information on these — and links to the paper proposing they are removed.  The functions are not widely implemented.

Comment: Uhhh, `rsize_t` -- I see the problem. Link this by accident with an MS C library ;) Thanks for the links!