# C loop not breaking

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to understand why the following program acts in such a weird way. I declare an array of chars, and input chars into it, with a while loop and scanf. However when I input letters, or digits, it runs seemingly forever. If I input a large number, or a string, it stops. Why doesn't it exit the loop after 5 iterations?

```
// This program runs forever if we input single-digit numbers
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    char u[5] = {0,};
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
        scanf(" %s", &u[i]);
    }
    printf("%s\n", u);
}
```

Comment: what is "almost forever"?

Comment: Cannot replicate the problem, works fine for me.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I haven't tested, but I input a digit, and then it asks for another input, so on and so forth for many many times. way more than 5

Comment: First of all, `%s` matches a sequence of non-whitespace characters. This code overflows your array.

Comment: I'm using Debian with gcc

Comment: @Marievi :) UB, UB everywhere..

Comment: read the man page for `scanf()`.

Comment: How are you entering your single-digit numbers? White space separated or newline separated?

Comment: @FelixPalmen could you please explain a little more what I did wrong?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I press enter after every single digit I input

Comment: The last (5th) digit you enter also writes an extra `\0` beyond the array bounds which is Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Why not use `%c`

Comment: You can't expect multiple characters to fit into a single one? Read a `scanf()` manual. And better, don't use `scanf()` at all.

Comment: @SouravGhosh of course I first went to cplusplus.com, but I couldn't understand all of it, so that's why I've come here for a explanation in English

Comment: Search for `man scanf`. Learn about strings and arrays in C. Then read [this FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35178520/2371524). Then read my [beginners' guide away from `scanf()`](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is broken beyond repair.

`scanf("%s", ...)` is **always** a severe bug, because you can't know your input in advance, and `%s` matches any sequence of non-whitespace characters, of any length -- there's **no** way to know how large your buffer must be.

`%s` writes the characters it reads starting at the address you pass as argument. It writes an additional `0` byte as the end mark of a string. So with your code, even if you only enter single characters, the last iteration writes this `0` byte at `u[5]` which is out of bounds, you overflowed your buffer.

You can't even fix it by just changing `%s` to `%c` (which matches a single character) because you don't add a `0` byte to the end of your array, so the array content **is not a string** and passing it to `printf("%s", ...)` is again **undefined behavior**.

Start over, read a good book on C first, and when you're done, best forget about `scanf()` and use better methods for input like `fgets()`. See also [How to read / parse input in C? The FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35178520/2371524) and my [beginners' guide away from `scanf()`](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html).

Comment: But why doesn’t it break from the for loop after 5 iterations ?

Comment: @blz because undefined behavior is undefined. Anything could happen when you e.g. overflow a buffer.