# C language: why my user input mixed with my printf

Tags: c

I want to wrote a program with `menu` and in case the user select `1` until `4` i have simple `switch`:

```
int main() {

    char str1[127];
    char str2[127];
    int result;
    int option = 0;

    while (option < 1 || option > 4)
    {
        printoptions();
        scanf("%d", &option);

        switch (option)
        {
        case 1:

            printf("Please enter first string: ");
            gets(str1);

            printf("Please enter second string: ");
            gets(str2);

            // bla bla

            break;

        case 2:
            break;

        case 3:

            break;

        case 4:
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    printf("\nPress any key to continue");
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

So my problem here is that after the user select the option `1` i can see this output:

```
Please enter first string: Please enter second string:
```

Why this is happening ?

Comment: Don't use `gets`. Don't *ever* use it! It is a dangerous function, and for that reason have been removed from the C standard. Use e.g. [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead.

Comment: OK but if i use scanf and the user input is "test " i can see the the input in only "test' without the empty space

Comment: @user979033 use [`fgets`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm)

Comment: `scanf("%d")` doesn't consume the newline character generated when you press `Enter` after the number. It is consumed by the first `gets()` that reads an empty string this way.

Comment: Mixing `scanf` and `fgets` is a bad idea. And so is using `scanf` for user input.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5240807/1023911

Comment: Generic links: [How to read / parse input in C? The FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35178520/2371524) and [A beginners' guide away from `scanf()`](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html). Next time have a look at the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info) first. And repeating earlier comments here: **don't EVER use `gets()`!!**

Comment: @FelixPalmen that is true. I think OP needs better error handling in that case.