# For loop skip second and later scanf

Tags: c

I have notice that only first scanf from for loop is asked and rest of them skip scanf request.

```
int main()
{
    int c = 0;
    int i;

    struct book
    {
        char name[20];
        float price;
        int page;
    };

    printf("\n enter number of book to add\n ");
    scanf("%d", &c);
    struct book b[c];
    printf("\n book details  \n ");

    for (i = 1; i < c; i++)
    {
        printf("\n enter name for book %d", i);
        scanf(" %c", &b[i].name);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\n enter price for book %d", i);
        scanf(" %f", &b[i].price);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\n enter page for book %d", i);
        scanf(" %d", &b[i].page);
    }
}
```

OUTPUT

> enter number of book to add  3
>
> book details      enter name for book 1james
>
> enter price for book 1
>
> enter page for book 1
>
> enter name for book 2
>
> enter price for book 2
>
> enter page for book 2

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question doesn't seem to have an actual question in it at the moment, you'll likely receive more help if you edit it.

Comment: Please note that calling `fflush` in an input-only stream (like `stdin`) is explicitly marked as *undefined behavior* in the C specification. Some libraries implement it as an extension of the language, but it's not portable and not something you really should do.

Comment: [How to read / parse input in C? The FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35178520/how-to-read-parse-input-in-c-the-faq).

Comment: As for your problem, think about what you attempt to read for the name!

Comment: Rule of thumb: scanf is confusing, and should not be used while learning the language.  If you invest time learning scanf, you're not learning C; your're learning the scanf formatting language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
scanf(" %c",&b[i].name);
```

looks super wrong, it reads a single character which doesn't make sense as a name, and also doesn't match your usage.

You likely meant:

```
scanf("%19s", b[i].name);
```

but that's bad too, since `%s` will stop at whitespace and book titles can have multiple words. Better to use `fgets()` to get full lines, then parse them.

Make sure you *check the return value* of all `scanf()` calls before relying on them having succeeded! I/O is brittle and can fail.

Comment: @mch True, cleaned that up.

Answer (score 1):

Correct your below statement:-

```
scanf(" %c",&b[i].name);  to scanf("%19s",b[i].name);
```

Because this is a string not a character variable. To read a string you need to use `%s` but not `%c`. We use `%c` to read a single character only. For example

```
char sex;

scanf(" %c",&sex);
```

Also in the case of an array we don't need to provide `&`, array itself behave like a pointer in C/C++.

Comment: `scanf(" %s",b[i].name);` lacks a width limit, much like the now obsolete `gets()`.  If `scanf()` is used, use a width limit like `scanf("%19s",b[i].name);`

Comment: @chux, great! thanks for your advice. I have modified my answer?