# Sscanf a string with data

Tags: c, memory, scanf

I have a string that contains a data, `"2013-04-20T13:50:47.390"` like this.

I was thinking of methods to work with the string values. I would like to use `sscanf`, since it seems an efficient way to do so, but I don't know the commands I need to add in the `sscanf` so it know the separators like '-', 'T', ':', '.'. Any suggestion?

Btw, is there any efficient way to *cut* the string, I would like to save in another string the part after the `T`.

Thanks for the time.

Comment: What have you tried?  A pointer to the digit after the ‘T’ would give you the remainder.  You could use `strdup()` (a POSIX standard function, but not a standard C function) to copy and save it if need be.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read / parse input in C? The FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35178520/how-to-read-parse-input-in-c-the-faq)

Comment: Note that both the answers currently available would accept `"    12-4-  3T  13:  50:  4.      1"` as valid input, and would report the milliseconds as `1` in both that and `"2013-04-20T13:50:47.1"`, rather than as 100 milliseconds, which is more accurate.  That doesn't automatically mean the answers are wrong.  It does mean it is harder than you'd like to parse a date string with `sscanf()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
int year, month, day, hour, min, sec, msec;
int ret;
ret = sscanf(str, "%4d-%2d-%2dT%2d:%2d:%2d.%d", 
             &year, &month, &day, &hour, &min, &sec, &msec);
if (ret != 7) {
    printf("Error while parsing time");
}
```

**EDIT**: As mentioned by @DavidBowling in comments, the `2` in format specifier `%2d` tells sscanf to read up to `2` digits for the associated integer.

Comment: What does the '04' '02' represent? Byte size?

Comment: Maybe you should add an explanation for the field width specifier to your answer; that would be helpful to OP. You don't need the `0` in `%02`, though. In fact, it might be a little bit confusing because: 1) in most other places `02` would be an octal integer constant, and 2) zeroes are meaningful in `fprintf()` family format strings.

Comment: @DavidBowling, Thank you for your explanation. I thought the `0` may remove the confusion about octal numbers, now after testing, I figured out you are right :). I will edit my post.

Comment: @DavidBowling: actually, the `0` prefix in the source string would be meaningful for a `%i` conversion specifier where it would indeed indicate an octal encoded number. Both `%d` and `%u` expect decimal encoded integers (`d` is for decimal). The size indicators in the format string are only needed to reject a source string where some of the fields would have too many digits. If there is no need for a stricter parser, `"%d-%d-%dT%d:%d:%d.%d"` could be used instead.

Comment: @chqrlie -- Sure. I was only talking about the format string, where (unless I am missing something) the `fscanf()` functions interpret the number following `%` and the optional assignment suppression character (`*`) as a decimal integer. Of course, zero prefixes in the source string (or elsewhere in the code) may be meaningful. The original answer had a format string like: `"%4d-%02d-%02dT%02d:%02d:%02d.%d"`. That, and the erroneous suggestion that here `0` tells `sscanf()` about possible leading zeros, is what the comments were directed at.

Comment: @DavidBowling: we are in complete agreement. I had not seen the original answer. My comment was primarily trying to teach other readers about the lesser known `%i` conversion specifier.

Comment: @chqrlie -- it is always good to point out that `%i` may behave a little differently than naively expected: so many nuances to come to grips with in using `fscanf()`! I was similarly interested in commenting on the peculiar appearance of a decimal value that at first glance might appear to be octal ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, i found how to do it. I just needed to add the separatores to the sscanf:

```
    sscanf(stringTest,"%d-%d-%dT%d:%d:%d.%d", &year,&month,&day,&hour,&min,&sec,&ms);
```