# How to populate arrays from file contents?

Tags: c

I want to read the contents of a file and sort them. The input file has a single column and records three attributes so it's like:

> 11579704
>   Man
>   Leo
>   11579704
>   Man
>   Joey
>   11579704
>   Man
>   Franny
>   11579704
>   Auto
>   Lucy
>   18919736
>   Man
>   Jose

I've set up 3 arrays and I want to populate each array with one of the criteria i.e. an array for all Car plates.

```
FILE* filePtr = fopen("vehicle.txt", "r");

while (!feof(filePtr)) /* while not End of File */
{
fscanf(filePtr, "%s%s%s", InputFileArray1[i], InputFileArray2[i], InputFileArray3[i]);
i++; /* increment counter */

} /*end while */
```

Should the above read from the file and populate the arrays or is it rubbish???

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Comment: What do you expect between the three sequences of non-whitespace? `%s%s%s` You might want to use strtok() instead. Please show sample input.

Comment: http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35178520/how-to-read-parse-input-in-c-the-faq

Comment: Who or what text suggested using `while (!feof(filePtr))`?

Comment: what should I use?