# Read integer untill user reaches negative integer or numbers of integer reaches upto 15

Tags: c

i wrote following program but it is not right. would you please assist me where i went wrong?

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{ 
    int count=0,a;
    do
    {
       scanf("%d",&a);
       if(a>0 )
       {
         for(count=0;count<15;count++);
           else;
       }
       while(int>=0);
    }
```

So would you tell me the correct code?

Comment: What makes you think it is not right? Crash? Hang? Misbehaviour? Compiler errror?

Comment: I formatted and indented your program for you. Look at it. I think the problems are obvious now. Or maybe not, did you double check that the code you show here is identical to the code you have? Please copy paste instead of typing again. I cannot believe that this code even compiles. What are the errors your compiler tells you? Did you copmile strictly, e.g. at least with `gcc -Wall`? Please edit the code until it at least compiles without errors. Better without errors and warnings. Ideally without errors or strict warnings.

Comment: The code after your edit still looks like: broken snytax for `if-else`, `do-while` and `main`. Also the newly added `for` loop does not have an effect. Would you like to base your code on working example from tutorials? Start with a HelloWorld. Add in a correct `do-while`. Insert a working `if-else`. Insert a working `for`. Add to place the code you want.

Comment: so would you tell me the correct code sir. i am newbie in programming

Comment: I provided the syntax elements, which you really should have picked up from a tutorial or book. Now the actual problem of your code is the question. What is not working? You did not ask a question here about the syntax of random constructs, instead you are trying to achieve a certain behaviour, aren't you? Talk about that, after you edited your code to actually be what you have at your place. Make a [mcve]. Double check that the code you post here acts as the one at home.

Comment: there was no any syntax misstake when i compiled

Comment: Which means that the code you compiled is very different from the one you show here. Please make sure they are identical. Do not type again. Copy paste after turning the code you compile into a MCVE and compiled again.

Comment: What makes you think it is not right? Crash? Hang? Misbehaviour? Compiler errror?

Comment: i wrote the same code which is written here but the problem is program should read only integer until user enter negative integer or number of positive integer reaches up to 15

Comment: If the code you show here is identical to the code you compile  successfully at home, then you have a - lets say - extremly interesting compiler. Please double check that the code here and at home are identical and also please double check that you really compile the code you are looking at and not accidentally any other code in your file system.

Comment: i wrote for(count=0;count<15;count++); when i use ; for is supposed to end . there is no need of { and }. same happens with else statement . so my syntax was right.

Comment: That is at least correct syntax, but it does not do anything.

Comment: What makes you think it is not right? Crash? Hang? Misbehaviour? Compiler errror?

Comment: Please take the [tour] again, read [ask] and study and apply the concept of making a [mcve]. Also have a look at this checklist: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/

Comment: Alternatively, if you code is as short as what you showed here, [edit] your question, delete the code which is there, copy the code you compile at home and paste it again. I will even take care of correct formatting for you.

Comment: The shown code cannot be compiled without errors, at least for the misplaced `else;` and the botched loop condition. It also contains an endless loop and a useless loop and (most harmless of all) you seem to have forgotten the last closing `}`.  I pay your dinner for a year (if you come here) if that code is actually compiled without errors. Please, please double check that the shown code is identical to the code you compile successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Please use building blocks of correct syntax:

main:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{ 
    /* other code */
    return 0;
}
```

do-while:

```
do
{
    /* other code */
} while(count>=0);
```

if:

```
if(a>0 )
{
    /* code if true */
} else
{
    /* code if false */
}
```

for:

```
for(a=0;a<15;a++)
{
    /* repeated code */
}
```

For getting input right, please read:

http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html
[How to read / parse input in C? The FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35178520/how-to-read-parse-input-in-c-the-faq)

When the syntax is right and the input is done correctly, then we can discuss the behaviour of your code; which I think is what you are actually asking about.   Though what you are describing might already be solved/achieved once you spend some work on how to get input properly, based on the links above.