# How to write a program, that reads 2 float numbers using scanf() with sum, difference, product, division and average?

Tags: c

I have a problem with my code in C.
All I have done is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float zahlen[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        printf("%d. Zahl", i + 1);
        scanf_s("%d", &zahlen[i]);
    }
    printf("Division: %f\n", zahlen[0]/zahlen[1]);
    printf("Produkt: %f\n", zahlen[0]*zahlen[1]);
    printf("Summe: %f\n", zahlen[0]+zahlen[1]);
    printf("Diffenrenz: %f\n", zahlen[0]-zahlen[1]);
    printf("Mittelwert: %f\n", (zahlen[0]+zahlen[1])/2);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Would appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: What about you code does not work?

Comment: Give us the error returned

Comment: Did you try `scanf_s("%f", &zahlen[i]);`?

Comment: If we run the program, the results are always 0

Comment: Look at the comment just above yours

Comment: CannedMoose, yes I tried that

Comment: The values is always 0, but the program kinda works

Comment: @Serkan Did you enter `.` or something else as decimal separator? You need to enter `.` for floating point values.

Comment: You ignore the success/failure indication of the scanner function. You state the values are always 0 (which is probably the quasi-random value of an uninitialised variable - and UB). You do division by those values. You should get division by zero problems. The code cannot possibly achieve any of its goals. I think you have a weird idea of "kinda works".

Comment: Save time.  Enable all compiler warnings.  A well enabled compiler will report issues with `float zahlen[2]; scanf_s("%d", &zahlen[i]);` and save us all time.  This is more efficient that posting on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `scanf_s()` function is trying to read an integer in base 10 and store it into a float variable.  Therefore when you try to enter `3.14` for the first number, `scanf_s()` will stop at the "." character (but leave it in the input stream).  When you try to read the second decimal integer, it will enter an infinite loop waiting for a character it can consume.

Short answer: Change the `%d` in `scanf_s()` to `%f`.

Answer (score 0):

You handle floats

```
 float zahlen[2];
```

You scan for integers, using `"%d"`:

```
scanf_s("%d", &zahlen[i]);
```

Whatever problem you are referring to, this needs to be fixed.
To do so read the documentation for scanner functions and afterwards:

http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html
[How to read / parse input in C? The FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35178520/how-to-read-parse-input-in-c-the-faq)