# Duplicated output values

Tags: c, duplicates

I want to display the calendar data in **ascending** order.

If the date appears several times I need to display it once.
The code **works** if the **date appears five or less times** in the input, 
if the date appears more than five times at the output it will show up twice.

I don't see the error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct date {
  int zi;
  int luna;
};
int main() {

  int n, i, j, k = 0, l;
  char c;
  scanf("%d", &n);
  struct date v[100];
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    scanf("%d %c %d", &v[i].zi, &c, &v[i].luna);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
    for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
      if (v[i].luna > v[j].luna) {
        struct date temp = v[i];
        v[i] = v[j];
        v[j] = temp;
      } else if (v[i].luna == v[j].luna && v[i].zi > v[j].zi) {
        struct date temp = v[i];
        v[i] = v[j];
        v[j] = temp;
      }
    }
  }

  printf("\n");
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      if (v[i].luna == v[j].luna && v[i].zi == v[j].zi && i != j) {
        printf("\nOK\n");
        for (l = j; l < n - 1; l++) {
          //    v[l].luna=v[l+1].luna;
          //    v[l].zi=v[l+1].zi;
          v[l] = v[l + 1];
        }
        n--;
      }
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {

    if (v[i].luna < 10 && v[i].zi >= 10) {

      printf("%d-0%d\n", v[i].zi, v[i].luna);
    } else if (v[i].zi < 10 && v[i].luna >= 10) {

      printf("0%d-%d\n", v[i].zi, v[i].luna);
    } else if (v[i].zi < 10 && v[i].luna < 10) {

      printf("0%d-0%d\n", v[i].zi, v[i].luna);
    } else
      printf("%d-%d\n", v[i].zi, v[i].luna);
  }
}
```

Comment: What did you find when you debugged your code using the simplest possible input that gives unexpected output?

Comment: Time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), especially how to use a debugger to step through your code line by line.

Comment: Related: [How to read / parse input in C? The FAQ.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35178520/how-to-read-parse-input-in-c-the-faq) (Especially with regards to using `scanf()` on potentially malformed user input *without checking the return code*.) Also, not a [mcve].

Comment: And, please choose a better title which describes the actual problem.

Comment: @jan The code review site is for code that works correctly. This code doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Anyway this question is about the community debugging his code. That's not what stack exchange is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be this block:

```
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      if (v[i].luna == v[j].luna && v[i].zi == v[j].zi && i != j) {
        printf("\nOK\n");
        for (l = j; l < n - 1; l++) {
          //    v[l].luna=v[l+1].luna;
          //    v[l].zi=v[l+1].zi;
          v[l] = v[l + 1];
        }
        n--;
      }
    }
  }
```

When you remove a duplicate (i.e. by shifting all elements towards the start and decrementing `n`) you still increment `j`. Consequently, your loop will skip one element and you may end up with duplicates.

The solution could be as simple as decrementing `j` at the same time as you decrement `n`.

BTW: It seems strange that the `j`-loop start from zero. I would expect it to start from `i+1`

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the problem!