# I can't understand professor's code about malloc

Tags: c, string, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

Professor give me a homework about malloc, dynamic memory allocate...
So He give me some hints about code but I can't understand his code and hints.
I think my code needs another 'def' or 'for loop'...
Anyway.

*question* Now I can gets_s some string with pointer. but I can't build.
   Print like alien language...
 last of this page I hope this code would be work.
  for (j=0;j<3;j++)
    printf("your sentence is %s ", *parray[i])

I tried some of codes with friends. he also can't figure out..
Professor told me This code is for beginner, "IT's easy to solve"

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void main() {
    char* parray[3];
    int i, j;
    char str[70]; // temporary save place
    for (i = 0; i< 3; i++) {        //
        printf("sentence, please. : ");
        gets_s(str, sizeof(str));   //dynamic memory allocate
        parray[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)**str);
        printf("\n");


free(parray[i]);
```

I hope this code work.

```
for (j=0;j<3;j++)
    printf("your sentence is %s ", *parray[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be allocating the amount of characters there was in the input string, +1 for the null terminator.

`parray[i] = malloc(strlen(str)+1);`

Then copy the data from temporary `str` to the new memory location.

Also avoid `gets_s` and use `fgets` instead. The bounds-checking interface of C11 is poorly supported in general, but this particular function was just some placeholder when rewriting old code using obsolete `gets`.

Comment: thanks! I'll try it again! and, If you had time, can you tell me about how to save another memory location? just parray[i] = another location[j] would be okay?

Comment: I don't like the `_s` functions, either, but if you tell someone to use `fgets`, you also have to teach them how to strip the newline.  (An unfortunate nuisance for both you and them.)

Comment: @SteveSummit It's not just me but C11 annex K explicitly recommends us not to use the function. As for fgets tutorials, feel free to contribute to this community wiki FAQ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35178520/how-to-read-parse-input-in-c-the-faq

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I see more and more questioners using the `_s` functions these days, though, so somebody's getting through to them... :-(

Comment: @SteveSummit Microsoft has been preaching these `_s` functions for some 20 years. And one problem is that they aren't 100% compatible with C11 annex K "bounds checking interface" (which was quite a fiasco).