# How to reject a non-numeric input in this code?

Tags: c

I tried using value of scanf but the code does not run properly.

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<math.h>

int main() {
  float dollars;
  int p, i = 0, count = 0;
  do {
    printf("Change owed:");
    scanf("%f", &dollars);
    if (dollars < 0) {
      printf("Foo\n");
    }
  } while (dollars < 0);

  int cents = round(dollars * 100);
  int denom[] = {25, 10, 5, 1};
  while (cents >= 1) {
    if (cents >= denom[i]) {
      count++;
      cents = cents - denom[i];
    } else {
      i++;
    }
  }
  printf("%d\n", count);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Looks like line endings composted during pasting.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not run properly"?

Comment: Do not use float for currency dollars. Instead use int for cents.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Assuming that the input is your problem see http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35178520/how-to-read-parse-input-in-c-the-faq

Comment: You say you "tried using value of scanf", but in your code you completely ignore the value returned by scanf.

Comment: Why are you using `scanf`?  It doesn't seem like this program needs to be reading its input at all.  Rather, the value you want to work with should be taken from `argv`

Comment: If I take int p=scanf("%f",&dollars) and for p=0,  take another condition, then the while loop runs infinitely.

Comment: SakshiPandita You get an endless loop with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63623378/how-to-reject-a-non-numeric-input-in-this-code/63623481#comment112506976_63623378) as it does not consume the non-numeric data like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63623481/2410359).

Answer (score 1):

> How to reject a non-numeric input in this code?

Check the return value of `scanf("%f", &dollars);`.  Use `getchar()` until the end-of-line to read the rest of the line and then read again when the scan count was 0.

```
int cnt;
do {
  cnt = scanf("%f", &dollars);
  if (cnt == EOF) {
    return 0; // no input
  }
  int ch;
  while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n') && ch != EOF) {
    ;
  }
} while (cnt == 0);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

See the trick here: scanf returns the number of succesfully read variables. Working with currencies would be better if you do it as integers (e.g: 1 dolar = 100 cents, so 1.85 dolar = 185 cents).

If you provide an integer, it wouldnt read the dot and the cents part (assume that should be 0 maybe?).

If it couldn't read at least the integer part then you report the error.

```
int main() 
{
   int dolar, cent = 0, read;
   read = scanf("%d.%d", &dolar, &cent);
   if(read < 1)
       printf("You didnt provide input in a valid format\n");
   else
       printf("Number provided was: %d.%d\n", dolar, cent);
}
```

Comment: As OP  is looking for resilient input detection, input like `"123.4"` will form $123.04.  `"123. 45"` forms $123.45,  `"123.-12"` forms $122.88  `"-123.45"` forms $-122.55.  The `"%d.%d"` approach makes for additional complications handled well enough with `scanf("%f", &dollars); ... int cents = round(dollars * 100.0);`

Comment: The value returned by `scanf()` is not the number of read characters.  It is the number of successful conversions that assigned to a variable — meaning that assignment-suppressing conversions such as `%*d` don't get counted (and neither does `%n`, but that's a different special case).  The value might also be EOF.  For `scanf("%d.%d", …);`, the return values might be EOF, 0, 1, 2.  Note that entering `10.9` will give the same result as `10.09` and you might run into problems because of that.