# Restrict symbols that is typed or else print error and go back to menu

Tags: c

I wanna restrict symbols that is typed or else print error and go back to menu. It means that if i type $ it happens an error and it goes back to operators menu, how to do this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<windows.h>

int main()
{

char op;
int a, b =0;
int res =0;

{
 SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),BACKGROUND_GREEN|BACKGROUND_INTENSITY);
    printf("\n\nBASIC CALCULATOR!");

    x:
printf ("\nType the operator: +, -, * or /\n");}
scanf("%c", &op);

if (op == '+' || op == '-' || op == '*' || op == '/')
{
printf ("\nType 2 numbers:\n");
scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
}
else {
    printf ("...\n");

}

 switch (op){

 case '+':
res = a + b;
printf ("...\n\n");
printf ("Result = %d\n", res);

 break;

 case '-':
res = a - b;
printf ("...\n");
printf ("Result = %d\n", res);
 break;

 case '*':
res = a * b;
printf ("...\n");
printf ("Result = %d\n", res);
 break;

 case '/':
res = a / b;
printf ("...\n");
printf ("Result = %d\n", res);
 break;


 default:

printf ("\n\n...");

 }
fflush(stdin);
goto x;
return (0);
}
```

updateddd

I don't have that much knowledge about libraries, i tried simple functions

Comment: `printf ("Result = %d\\n", res);` <<-- no need to double the `'\'`

Comment: Lose the `goto` and use a `while` loop instead.

Comment: @wildplasser Isn't it something do with new SO editor update? Excess back-ticks & escape-backslashes.

Comment: is this if op line right?

Comment: @SparKot Could be. There's also an extra `'` at the beginning and end of the question.

Comment: @wildplasser ye, miss typed

Comment: @JohnnyMopp how can i put anything other than the operators will go back to menu without bugs??

Comment: `do { // get input } while (op != ‘+’ && op != ‘-‘ && op != ‘*’ && op != ‘/‘)`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp can i do this with scanf?

Comment: [parse input in C? The FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35178521/835145). If you enter invalid data, `scanf()` is not your friend. You'll end with an infinite loop.

Comment: [apart from the semantics] `if (op == '+' || '-' || '*' || '/') {
        printf ("Type 2 numbers:\n");
        scanf ("%d%d", &a, &b);
    } else {
        printf ("COULD NOT GET ANY OPERATOR!\n");
        goto x;
    }` is handled in the switch below. No need to treat it specially.

Comment: @wildplasser it bugs my program, it accepts the situation '$' as an operator and shows the message, while it asks for numbers no operation can be done from there, like operator menu or any number calculation...

Comment: `scanf ("%c", &op);` --> `scanf (" %c", &op);`  (Add space)

Comment: "Restrict symbols that is typed" --> It is not possible to restrict what is _typed_.  `scanf()` can  be used to restrict what is _read_, but  unacceptable input remains in `stdin`.

Comment: hey, i finally fixed this, y'all can send me dollars to use my calculator, haha
just edited on main topic