# How to write two functions for getting an array and display that array in c

Tags: arrays, c, function, arguments

**function for get array from the user**

```
#include <stdio.h>
void getArray()
{
   
    
     printf("Enter size of array: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
 
     printf("Enter %d elements in the array : ", n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    }
```

**function for display array**

```
void displayArray(){
    
    printf("\nElements in array are: ");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
 
    {
        printf("%d  ", a[i]);
    }
}
```

**Both functions are called in the main**

```
int main(){
    int a[1000],i,n;
    getArray();
     displayArray();
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is how to pass the array that we get from the user to the display array function and both functions can be called in the main and also the array want to declare in the main function

Comment: The usual: `scanf` of (potentially malformed) user input without checking return value. Use leading whitespace in format string to skip any number of whitespace in input. Check the number of elements against the size of your array to avoid overflow.

Comment: what you mean can you explain that

Comment: Usually, we pass the address of the first element of the array as an argument to the function that processes it. It is better to pass him his size too.

Comment: It will be very helpful for me if you can explain with code

Comment: Try [how to read / parse input in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35178520/how-to-read-parse-input-in-c-the-faq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example that does not handle input errors.
In order for your functions to have knowledge of the array, you must send them its address as well as its size.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getArray(int a[], int size_max)
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter size of array: ");
    while(1)
    {
        scanf("%d",&n);
        if(n>size_max) printf("The size must be less than %d: ", size_max);
        else break;
    }

    printf("Enter %d elements in the array : ", n);
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) scanf("%d", &a[i]);

    return n;
}

void displayArray(int a[], int n)
{
    printf("\nElements in array are: ");
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) printf("%d  ", a[i]);
}

int main()
{
    int a[1000];
    int n = getArray(a, 1000);
    displayArray(a, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass that shared variable as argument. Also return and use the returned value if reference not having valid data. Or else you need to pass this argument as reference instead of value like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int[] getArray(int a[])
{
 printf("Enter size of array: ");
scanf("%d",&n);

 printf("Enter %d elements in the array : ", n);
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    scanf("%d", &a[i]);
}
return a;
}
```

function for display array

```
void displayArray(int a[]){

printf("\nElements in array are: ");
for(i=0;i<n;i++)

{
    printf("%d  ", a[i]);
}
}
```

Both functions are called in the main

```
int main(){
    int a[1000],i,n;
    a = getArray(a);
     displayArray();
    return 0;
}
```