# scanf in switch case C programming

Tags: c, switch-statement, scanf

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char op;
    int num1, num2;
    printf("Enter the operation(+,-,/,*,!,^) :  ");
    scanf(" %c", &op);
    switch (op) {
      case '+':
        printf("Enter the first operand : ");
        scanf(" %d", num1);
        printf("Enter the second operand : ");
        scanf(" %d", num2);  
        printf("%d", num1 + num2);
        break;
    }
}
```

when I run this. code stops after me entering first operand. I added space before `scanf` but it didn't solve the problem below.

[image: output of code]

Comment: Don't post pictures of text. Post text as text. Output is text.

Comment: You'll need to discard the trailing line feed character from stdin. But that's not the only problem, you have some basic syntax errors `scanf(" %d",num1);` which the compiler should already have told you about: [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565)

Comment: @Lundin are you sure the dupe is correct?

Comment: Somewhat unrelated: your approach is somewhat wrong. Write the code for the `-` operator and you'll understand  what I mean.

Comment: @Jabberwocky There's several problems here. Though I don't know a dupe for "basic scanf syntax errors made by every beginner". Maybe this one is better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35178520/how-to-read-parse-input-in-c-the-faq

Comment: @Lundin I'mean with the space in front of the scanf conversion specifiers (which the OP has put in their code) it should work provided the `&` is added. The real problem is the missing `&` which the dupe does not address.

Comment: Note that you can take input before the switch statement. That way, you won't have to write the same code for every operator.

Comment: You only need the space before the conversion specifications which don't automatically skip white space — and there are only three of those: `%c`, `%[…]` (scan sets) and `%n`.  All the other conversion specifications skip white space automatically, whether you want them to or not.  And white space includes newlines, of course.  The `scanf()` function basically doesn't care about newlines — essentially, it can't be used reliably where you need line-based input.  Use `fgets()` or POSIX `getline()` to read a line, and  then use `sscanf()` or other functions to parse the line that was read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add the address operator (`&`)  in front of the `num1` and `num2` variables in the calls to `scanf`.

Modify those two lines like this:

```
scanf(" %d", &num1);
scanf(" %d", &num2);
//           ^add the &
```

Answer (score -1):

I usually add an & after the comma of every `scanf`
I mean really when your advancing and that mistake is not corrected it can be annoying:

```
scanf("%d", &var);
```

Comment: *"I usually add an & after the comma of every scanf"* Do you understand what function `&` even has?