# How do I correctly handle console operations with char type in C?

Tags: c, console, char, logic, console-application

I'm doing a logic exercise (begginer stuff) in which the user is presented with the options to type "A" for an arithmetic average of his school grades and "W" for a weighted average. The user then proceeds to provide three grades, the program calls for calculate_grades function and it displays in the terminal the average of the notes based on which type of average the user chose - PRETTY BASIC STUFF, I KNOW! Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

float calculate_grades(char letter, float grade1, float grade2, float grade3) {
    float average;

    if (letter == 'A' || letter == 'a')
        average = (grade1 + grade2 + grade3) / 3;
    else
        average = (grade1 * 5 + grade2 * 3 + grade3 * 2) / (5 + 3 + 2);

    return average;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    float grade1, grade2, grade3;
    char letter;

    do {
        printf("Enter the number of students:\n");
        scanf("%d", &n);

        if (n < 0)
            printf("Invalid input! The number of students should be greater than or equal to zero.\n");
    } while (n < 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        do {
            printf("Enter 'A' for arithmetic mean or 'W' for weighted mean:\n");
            scanf(" %c", &letter);
            if ((letter != 'A' && letter != 'a') && (letter != 'W' && letter != 'w'))
                printf("Invalid input! The options are 'A' for arithmetic mean and 'W' for weighted mean.\n");
        } while ((letter != 'A' && letter != 'a') && (letter != 'W' && letter != 'w'));

        do {
            printf("Enter the first grade:\n");
            scanf("%f", &grade1);
            if (grade1 < 0)
                printf("Invalid input! The grade should be greater than or equal to zero.\n");
        } while (grade1 < 0);

        do {
            printf("Enter the second grade:\n");
            scanf("%f", &grade2);
            if (grade2 < 0)
                printf("Invalid input! The grade should be greater than or equal to zero.\n");
        } while (grade2 < 0);

        do {
            printf("Enter the third grade:\n");
            scanf("%f", &grade3);
            if (grade3 < 0)
                printf("Invalid input! The grade should be greater than or equal to zero.\n");
        } while (grade3 < 0);

        printf("Student's average: %.2f pts\n", calculate_grades(letter, grade1, grade2, grade3));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, for some reason the terminal is displaying multiple lines of "invalid input" when the program reaches the part where it asks the user for the type of average to be calculated - not only when the user enters an invalid input (like "blablabla" or "lorem ipsum"), but even when the user enters valid input (like "a" or "W")! I have never handled character types in C this way before, so I don't know what is the problem and all solutions that GPT is offering are extremely complicated - which I'm certain aren't necessary, or my college teacher wouldn't have given us this exercise to begin with. What is the easy and obvious solution that I'm not seeing here?

Comment: One simple solution is to obtain every input with `fgets()` and analyse the string. If it's incorrect input another string. `scanf` is intended for *formatted* input not for wild user keyboard stabbing. It's quite unfriendly for that.

Comment: Code works for me. Have you saved the most recent edit changes before compiling? Is this the code that formed the executable? However, if I enter `0` students, there's no error message... Perhaps `if( n <= 0 )` and same for the `while()`...

Comment: you can simplify all those `letter != 'X' && letter != 'x'` to `tolower(letter) != 'x'`. It will make the code much easier to read and write.

Comment: If the user enters `xxxxx`, each scanf will read one character. So you'll get 5 "Invalid input" messages.

Comment: You must check the return value from `scanf()` to make sure it actually read data.  For example, if the user enters `QWERTY` for `scanf("%f", &grade2);`, `scanf()` will read nothing, leave `QWERTY` in the input buffer, and leave `grade2` unchanged. As currently written, depending on the value in the uninitialized `grade2`, that will either result in an infinite loop that the user can't break without killing the entire program, or the problem will cascade to the next `scanf()` loop where the problem will repeat with `grade3` replacing `grade2`. `scanf()` isn't user unfriendly, it's **HOSTILE**.

Comment: The super common beginner problem everyone is struggling with is the trailing new line characters that the various stdio.h functions like to leave behind in stdin. Check out [How to read / parse input in C? The FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35178520/how-to-read-parse-input-in-c-the-faq) for general advise.