# How to convert a hex string to decimal in c

Tags: c, hex, decimal

So I have been learning the *C Programming Language* by Kernighan and Ritchie. In chapter two, exercise 2.3 the `htoi` function which converts a string of hexadecimal digits to equivalent integer value problem. I saw many of ways to achieve this: rather than copying the solutions, I tried to implement my own version of solution. Still I can't figure out the shortest and easiest way to do this and try to implement the optional '**0x**' or '**Ox**' scenario. here below is my code

how can I implement the optional '**0x**'?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char *reverse(char s[]) {
    int len = strlen(s);
    char *r = (char * )malloc(len + 1);;
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = len; i > 0; i--) {
        r[k] = s[i - 1];
        k++;
    }
    r[k] = '\0';
    return r;
}

int check_valid(char *s) {
    int valid = 0;
    int not_valid = 0;

    int len  = strlen(s);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if ((s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9') || (s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'f') || (s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'F')) {
            valid = 1;
        } else
            not_valid = 1;
    }

    if (!not_valid) {
        return 1;
    } else
        return 0;
}

int rawint(char c ) {
    if(isalpha(c)) {
        return toupper(c) - 'A' + 10;
    } else 
        return c - '0';
}

int htoi(char *s) {
    char len = strlen(s);
    int power = 1;
    int dec = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        dec += rawint(s[i]) * power;
        power *= 16;
    }

    return dec;
}

int main() {

    char s[] = "7abc";;
    int check = check_valid(s);
    char *r = reverse(s);

    printf("reversed %s\n",r);      
    if (check) {
        int dec = htoi(r);
        printf("%d\n", dec);
    } else {
        printf("not OK");
    }
}
```

Comment: "implement the optional '0x' or 'Ox' scenario": which is what, exactly?

Comment: Perhaps the easiest way is to use the standard [`strtol`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strtol-wcstol-strtol-l-wcstol-l?view=msvc-170) function and then `sprintf()` rather than writing your own. It will ignore any leading `0x` or `0X` when told base 16.

Comment: ...and will correctly interpret it when told base 0 ("figure it out on your own") as well. I will *strongly* advice against homegrown implementations, *unless* you are in the business of implementing the standard library. In the latter case, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425730/difference-between-scanf-and-strtol-strtod-in-parsing-numbers) for an interesting edge case -- "0xz".

Comment: @DevSolar but not without the `0x` for example which base is `1234`?

Comment: @WeatherVane: Correct, that would be interpreted as base 10.

Comment: My own (CC0) implementation of `strto*()` consists of a [prelim function](https://github.com/DevSolar/pdclib/blob/master/functions/_PDCLIB/_PDCLIB_strtox_prelim.c) and a [main function](https://github.com/DevSolar/pdclib/blob/master/functions/_PDCLIB/_PDCLIB_strtox_main.c), with the actual [strtol](https://github.com/DevSolar/pdclib/blob/master/functions/stdlib/strtol.c) (and strtoul, strtoll etc.) merely being a wrapper around those.

Comment: @devMe What should happen with unusual input like `"xyz"`,  `"123xyz"`,  `"0x"`,  `""`,  `"-123"`, `"123456781234567812345678123456781234567812345678"`, ?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with trying to come up with your own solution, but if you read chapter 2 of the book, you saw how K&R implement the function `atoi` to perform the conversion from decimal representation to an `int` value.

The code in the book does not accept initial blank characters nor handle an optional `+` or `-` sign, but it does perform the conversion in a very concise and effective way, consuming one digit at a time from the string.

Your solution OTOH allocates memory (which is not freed) for a reverse copy of the string and `htoi` parses the string in reverse order, which complicates the computation and as you insist on checking for proper digits in `check_valid`, the prefix (or in this case the `x0` or `X0` suffix) is rejected.  The main problem is `htoi` does not have the proper semantics: it should convert `0x7abc` as `31420` directly.

You can modify the `atoi` code from the book to handle hexadecimal representation and an optional prefix this way:

```
unsigned htoi(const char s[]) {
    int i = 0;
    unsigned n = 0;

    /* skip an optional 0x or 0X prefix */
    if (s[0] == '0' && (s[1] == 'x' || s[1] == 'X'))
        i = 2;

    for (;;) {
        /* parse the string one digit at a time, stop on the first non digit */
        unsigned digit;
        char c = s[i++];
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            digit = c - '0';
        else
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f')
            digit = c - 'a' + 10;
        else
        if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F')
            digit = c - 'A' + 10;
        else
            break;
        n = 16 * n + digit;
    }
    return n;
}
```

Note these remarks:

- type `unsigned` is more appropriate than `int` for this conversion to avoid undefined behavior on large values such as `0xFFFFFFFF`
- `s` is defined as `const char s[]`, or equivalently `const char *s` to allow calling `htoi` with string literals and other constant strings without a warning.
- `htoi` should also accept initial white space and an optional sign, but this is left for another exercise
- like the book's `atoi`, `htoi` stops on the first character that is not a proper digit, it does not check and *reject* malformed strings.
- the code assumes that `abcdef` and `ABCDEF` are sequences of contiguous characters in the target character set.
- `i` should be defined with type `size_t` to accommodate for extremely long strings on platforms where `SIZE_MAX > INT_MAX`.

Comment: @Fe2O3: thanks! fixed. I wonder who DV'd and why?

Comment: Serial DVer walked though, hit everyone with no obvious comment - meh, such is life.

Answer (score 1):

> implement the optional '0x' or 'Ox' scenario.

Certainly OP meant "implement the optional '0x' or '0X' scenario."  (digit `'0'`, not the letter `'O'`).

> how can i implement the optional '0x'?

To check validity, add a test if lead characters match the 0x, 0X sequence.  If so, skip 2 `char`.

```
int check_valid(char *s){
  // Add
  if (s[0] == '0' && (s[1] == 'x' || s[1] == 'X')) {
    s += 2;
  }
```

---

**Bug**

Check for `valid` and `not_valid` to not consider `""` as valid.

```
// if( !not_valid ){
if(valid && !not_valid ){
    return 1;
```

---

Tip: rather than 2 passes down the string, iterate until the *null character* is found.

```
//int len  = strlen(s);
//for(int i = 0; i < len;i++){
for(int i = 0; s[i]; i++){
```

Answer (score 1):

When you're learning to code, it's often tempting to add more code in an effort to solve a problem. This tendency fades as experience is gained. I highlight this aspect noting that the OP's code has 4 functions to service the test being performed in `main()`. Factoring out code to "helper" functions is very good. However, in this case, there might be too much *off loading* happening.

One flaw not yet noted is the memory leak because the pointer return from `reverse()` is not `free()`'d. Typing the `free()` should follow typing `malloc()` just as typing `')'` follows typing `'('`. Heap allocations and releases **must** be balanced in a good program.

The function of `check_valid()` is debatable. Good that you are aware of data validation! Should `htoi()` be protected? Or, should it be left to do its best with whatever it is given? An open question... (`!not_valid` suggests you should have gone for a short walk. The code below shows how to use a Standard Library function to test if a letter is one of a particular subset of alphanumeric characters.)

`rawint()` might be better as in-line code, rather than the program performing a function call for each character being converted from ASCII to its binary value.

Finally, `htoi()` performs the another two traversals of the string (once to measure and once to convert characters). The characters are getting *dog-earred* by now.

Below is another version for your consideration (with a test suite of values). Learning can be very rewarding. This code is tiny and dense, but somewhat complex. Many things are happening in each line. This is to demonstrate another extreme that should be avoided. You want your readers to understand the code with having to dissect each symbol in relation to other symbols... Just a bit of fun on a rainy day.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned htoi(const char s[]) {
    char c[2] = {0};
    const char *lut = "0123456789ABCDEFabcdef";
    unsigned d, n = 0, i = 0;

    s += (s[0]=='0' && (s[1]=='x' || s[1]=='X')) ? 2 : 0;
    while( i < 8 && (c[0] = s[i++]) != 0 && lut[d = strcspn(lut, c)] )
        n = 16 * n + (( d<16 ) ? d : d-6);

    return n;
}

int main( void ) {
    char *s[] = {
        "Hello", "7FF", "0xff", "0XFF", "ff",
        "7FFFFFFF", "0xFFFFFFFF",
        "0x12345678", "0x123456789",
        "C0FFEE", "ABBA FOREVER",
        NULL,
    };
    int i = 0;

    do {
        printf( "%13s - %10u - %10u\n", s[i], strtoul(s[i], NULL, 16), htoi( s[i] ) );
    } while( s[++i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
        Hello -          0 -          0
          7FF -       2047 -       2047
         0xff -        255 -        255
         0XFF -        255 -        255
           ff -        255 -        255
     7FFFFFFF - 2147483647 - 2147483647
   0xFFFFFFFF - 4294967295 - 4294967295
   0x12345678 -  305419896 -  305419896
  0x123456789 - 4294967295 -  305419896 // Which behaviour is correct?
       C0FFEE -   12648430 -   12648430
 ABBA FOREVER -      43962 -      43962
```

Regarding the discrepancy in the return value, please refer to the man page for `strtoul()`... This toy code could be improved, yes?

Answer (score 0):

Here is *your* code, simplified and modified to accept optional "0x" prefix as you wished:

Dispenses with rawint() thanks to htoi() internal look up table.

Dispenses with check() by doing its own internal check on pointer returned by strchr()

UPDATE: sreverse() has dispensed with calls to malloc() and strlen()

htoi() Accepts strings with or without optional "0x" prefix

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/zvhvbaP1r) is runnable code to see that it works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

/* sreverse() 
 -- no longer has to allocate memory -- uses single char temp value 
 -- removed call to strlen() with tiny while() loop
*/
char *sreverse(char *s)
{
    int i=0, k=-1;
    char ch;

    while(s[++k]);  //get strlen

    for(i = 0, k-=1; k>i; i++, k--)
    {
        ch = s[k];
        s[k] = s[i];
        s[i] = ch;
    }
    return s;
}

/*
    htoi() 
    Updated:
    - Removed dependency on rawint()
    - Removed call to strlen() with for() loop mod
    - Uses Hex lookup table 'lut' and strchr()
    - Performs its own internal check for valid Hex string on the fly
    - Quits when valid '0x' prefix or end of string is encountered
    - Sets parameter success flag for success/fail
*/
int htoi(char *s, int *success)
{
    int i, dec=0, power = 1;
    char *p, *sr = sreverse(s), lut[]="0123456789ABCDEF";

    *success = 1; /* Assume success until proven otherwise */

    for (i = 0; sr[i]; i++) 
    {
        p = strchr(lut, toupper(sr[i]));
        if(p)
        {
            dec += (int)(p - lut) * power;
            power *= 16;
        }
        else
        {
            /* If we only failed look up because of "0x" prefix, that's a success */
            *success = (!strcmp( &sr[i], "x0"));
            break;
        }
    }
    return dec;
}


#define SAMPLES 6

int main()
{
    /* Samples are with/without "0x" prefix, upper and lowercase, etc */
    char s[SAMPLES][15] = { "7FF", "0xf", "ff", "0xFFFFFFFF", "0x7FG", "Hello" };
    int success, dec, runcount = 0;

    do{
        dec = htoi(s[runcount], &success);
        printf("Result %-7s: %-4d from string: %s\n", success?"SUCCESS":"FAIL", dec, sreverse(s[runcount++]));
    }while(runcount < SAMPLES);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
    Result SUCCESS: 2047 from string: 7FF
    Result SUCCESS: 15   from string: 0xf
    Result SUCCESS: 255  from string: ff
    Result SUCCESS: -1   from string: 0xFFFFFFFF
    Result FAIL   : 0    from string: 0x7FG
    Result FAIL   : 0    from string: Hello
```